# Docker seems to be running with the wrong volume

Tags: docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, docker-volume, docker-image

I have a web project that is written on the top of the ASP.NET Core 3.1 framework. I want to run the project in a docker container on a Linux virtual box.

I create the following `docker-compose.yml` file

```
version: '3.4'

services:
  myproject:
    image: ${DOCKER_REGISTRY-}myproject
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: myproject/Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - storage:/storage
      - ${APPDATA}/Microsoft/UserSecrets:/root/.microsoft/usersecrets:ro
      - ${APPDATA}/ASP.NET/Https:/root/.aspnet/https:ro
    environment:
      - ASPNETCORE_ENVIRONMENT=Development
      - ASPNETCORE_URLS=https://+:443;http://+:80
    ports:
      - 51736:80
      - 44344:443
volumes:
  storage:
```

When I execute `docker-compose up --build`

I get the following output

```
Successfully built b084cb989f05
Successfully tagged myproject:latest
Starting myproject_myproject_1 ... done
Attaching to myproject_myproject_1
myproject_1  | Unhandled exception. System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: /app/Storage/
myproject_1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root, ExclusionFilters filters)
myproject_1  |    at Microsoft.Extensions.FileProviders.PhysicalFileProvider..ctor(String root)
```

From the logs above the app is looking for `/app/Storage/` path to initialize the `PhysicalFileProvider`. I am not sure where that is coming from. According to my `docker-compose.yml` file, the storage volume should me `/storage` not `/app/Storage/`.

At some point, I had `storage:/app/Storage` in my `docker-compose.yml` file but it is no longer there. What could be causing the image to attach the wrong volume/storage folder?

**Updated**

Here is the content of the `Dockerfile`

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1-buster-slim AS base
WORKDIR /app
EXPOSE 80
EXPOSE 443

FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1-buster AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["myproject/myproject.csproj", "myproject/"]
RUN dotnet restore "myproject/myproject.csproj"
COPY . .
WORKDIR "/src/myproject"
RUN dotnet build "myproject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/build

FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "myproject.csproj" -c Release -o /app/publish

FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /app
COPY --from=publish /app/publish .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "myproject.dll"]
```

I tried the following command to delete everything

```
docker-compose down -v --rmi all --remove-orphans
docker-compose build --no-cache
```

However, I am still getting the same result. How can I correctly mount the `/storage` folder with the image?

Comment: Is your `Dockerfile` referring to `/app/Storage`?

Comment: `storage:/storage` absolute paths please

Comment: @DuDoff what would be the absolete path? I'll update my question with the contact of Dockerfile now

Comment: did you literally do `COPY . .` What you need to do is go into the folder, and type `pwd` if on terminal. if you're GUI, then `right click` -> `properties` -> `path` and translate that path into something like `Users/<my-user-name/Desktop/thisfolder/thisfile.txt` And then to copy the folder in my Dockerfile, I would do `COPY Users/<my-user-name>/Desktop/thisfolder /thisfolder`

Comment: `/app/publish` is probably in your `Users/John/Documents/something/app/publish` Get the full path and put it in!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The message is not related to docker-compose I think.

Something in the application is telling it to look at that folder. It's correct that the folder doesn't exist because the docker-compose doesn't create it.

Check the code or config in the ASP.NET application itself that provides this path. Or the docker command that runs the dotnet process als, or the environment variables set in the dockerfile.

#### Update:

Looking at your dockerfile, I'm guessing the app is looking for `storage` only not `/storage` (relative path not absolute path), and that's why you are getting the extra `/app` in the beginning (from the `workdir`).

Comment: I am a bit confused about the docker volume. what create the docker volume based on the configuration?

Comment: The docker compose creates the volume, but I think this is working right. I mean the volume is created right, the app is the one that's wrong, because the app is looking in the wrong dir. You need to check the app code that specifies where to look for the folder.

Comment: Looking at your dockerfile, I'm guessing the app is looking for `storage` only not `/storage` (relative path not absolute path), and that's why you are getting the extra `/app` in the beginning (from the `workdir`).

Comment: Something is wrong with the image. Because of the error points on line 32. I modified the code so that `storage` is all lower case yet the error shows capitalized `Storage` so when I build the image is it not building using the code is Visual Studio. Here is how I am setting the path to the storage using c# `private IWebHostEnvironment Env; Path.Combine(Env.ContentRootPath, "storage")`

Comment: The `Path.Combine` seems to intentionally add the `/app` you didn't want. I'm not sure. Also check how the dockerfile behaves when the build fails. Do `git clean -dfx` to remove any old files.

Comment: Just use "/storage" for the path and see how it works too.

Comment: I think you on to something. At what point in time I would need to create the "storage" folder and give permission to upload? I mean do I need to create it manually, or would that be part of the dockerfile? I don't want this file to get removed if the container is removed.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205894/discussion-between-john-and-meligy).